# Getting Count of New and Missing Rows by each date

Tags: mysql

I have a table structure like this.

```
+--------------------------+------------------------+
|  id |    date      | property_id | - other cols - |
+--------------------------+------------------------+
|  1  |   2012-12-04 |    102      |
|  2  |   2012-12-05 |    101      |
|  3  |   2012-12-05 |    102      |
|  4  |   2012-12-05 |    103      |
|  5  |   2012-11-07 |    101      |
|  6  |   2012-11-07 |    102      |
|  7  |   2012-11-07 |    103      |
|  8  |   2012-10-08 |    101      |
|  9  |   2012-10-08 |    102      |
|  10 |   2012-10-08 |    103      |
|  11 |   2012-10-08 |    104      |
+-----+--------------+-------------+-----------------+
```

This is a history table which tracks property price and other historical data over time. `id` is unique id, `property_id` has multiple entries over time. Batch entries of history data is made every week. For example for two different date we have same property id indicating price changes over two date.

Now what I need is to find a particular given period of time (date between).

1. Number of new properties are added compared to previous entry date.
2. Number of properties are missing from previous entry date.

I hope my explanation is clear enough.

### Edit

Changed #2 from previous week to previous entry date.

Comment: #2 is a little ambiguous

Answer (score 1):

For the first problem you can use the below query:

```
     Select count(distinct(property_id)) from table-name 
      where date Between start_date AND end_date 
      AND 
      property_id != ALL
      (
            Select distinct(property_id)
            from table-name 
            where date < start_date
      )
```

This will display all the new property _d's after the date start_date till end_date

For second one you can use this:

```
   Select count(distinct(property_id)) from table-name 
      where date < start_date
      AND 
      property_id != ALL
      (
            Select distinct(property_id)
            from table-name 
            where date Between start_date AND end_date
      )
```

This will display all the property_id's before the start_date which are not present within start_date and end_date

Comment: He wants `number of`, and I don't see any `count` statement in your code, I didn't go in detail

Comment: @varun OP doesnt specify `start_date` and `end_date` columns.

Comment: @imran these are not columns , these are dates between which the data is needed.

Answer (score 1):

## Sql Fiddle

Suppose,table name is `orders`

### Number of new properties is added compared to previous entry date.

```
SELECT 
  SUM(total.property_id_count) as total_property
FROM
  (
    SELECT   
      count(all_order.property_id) as property_id_count,
      date_order.property_id  from orders as all_order
    RIGHT JOIN 
      (SELECT orders.* FROM orders WHERE `date` BETWEEN $start_date  AND $end_date) as   date_order
ON all_order.id = date_order.id
GROUP BY all_order.property_id 
HAVING COUNT(all_order.property_id) > 1) AS total
```

### Number of properties is missing from previous week.

```
SELECT 
  SUM(total.property_id_count) as total_property
FROM
  (
    SELECT date_order.date,   
     count(all_order.property_id) as property_id_count,
     date_order.property_id  from orders as all_order
    RIGHT JOIN 
     (
       SELECT orders.* FROM orders
       where date between date_sub(now(),INTERVAL 1 WEEK) and now()
     ) as date_order
ON all_order.id = date_order.id
GROUP BY all_order.property_id 
HAVING COUNT(all_order.property_id) > 1

) as total
```